# Adding different styles to two glyphicons in the same pseudo cell

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I have a requirement where I need to have two different css styles which is displayed in the single pseudo cell.

I am using a class placing two unicode characters into one pseudo element. But I want two different colors for these two.

Please see the below css class:

```
.doubleSign:before {    
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e086\e101";
  font-size: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: -7px !important;
 }
```

How am I supposed to do that? Please help me. thanks.

Comment: can you provide a piece of your HTML?

Comment: I am sending it from a java class table.setHeaderStyle("weekdays", i - daysBefore, " dayinfo doubleSign");

Comment: You cannot do it with a single selector.

Comment: you can use  > :last-child > i thinks it's helpful

Comment: @ Lalit Bhakuni. Where to use :last:child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare two `pseudo` selector :before, :after on that `.doubleSign` and add `styling` to it individually as it's not possible to fetch them as single element.

```css
.doubleSign:before{    
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e086";
  font-size: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: -7px !important;
  color:blue;
}  
.doubleSign:after{    
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e101";
  font-size: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: -7px !important;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="doubleSign">

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @ShruthiSathyanarayana :-)

Answer (score 1):

put both symbols into different `<span>` or `<i>` to treat them with different CSS; because it is not possible to apply different CSS using single selector for both of the symbols.